# GHC could not execute gcc.exe in Yesod Installation

Tags: haskell, gcc, yesod, haskell-stack

I followed ["Yesod quick start guide"](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) to install Yesod in Windows 10.
But, when I issued the `stack build` command, it failed.

#### Environment

- Windows 10 (64bits)
- `stack-0.1.5` (for Windows10 64bits)
- No Haskell Platform

I executed these commands

1. stack new my-project yesod-sqlite && cd my-project
2. stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc
3. stack setup
4. stack build <--- the error occured

In 'stack build' command, the package installations were done. But, when it build the project, the error occured.

#### Command Prompt

```
>stack build

Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
my-project-0.0.0: build
Preprocessing library my-project-0.0.0...
In-place registering my-project-0.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'my-project' for my-project-0.0.0...
Linking .stack-work\dist\x86_64-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\my-project\my-project.exe ...
ghc.exe: could not execute: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.2\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe

--  While building package my-project-0.0.0 using:
      C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\stack-0.1.5.0\setup-exe-cache\setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\x86_64-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\ build lib:my-project exe:my-project --ghc-options  -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: You might need to install gcc. I don't know if Stack comes with that on Windows (most Linux boxes already have it).

Comment: gcc is shipped with GHC itself on Windows. This includes installations via GHC

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the argument length limit on Windows. Starting in GHC 7.10.3, GHC will support response files for sending linker arguments in order to bypass this limitation. In the meanwhile, a workaround is to manually make the path to your stack root shorter by setting the STACK_ROOT environment variable.

For more information, see https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/08/stack-ghc-windows

Comment: What a strange OS limitation!

Comment: Wait till you hear that filepaths are limited to 260 characters, unless of course your prefix them with the highly intuitive ``\\?\``.

Comment: I tried but still got the same error.  
1. I deleted all the stack folders to clear the environment.  
2. I unzipped "stack-0.1.5.0-x86_64-windows.zip" to "C:\stack_root".  
3. I set "STACK_ROOT=c:\stack_root" in the system environment variable.  
4. I opened the command prompt and move to "C:\" to create the project under "C:\"  
5. I executed "stack new my-project yesod-sqlite && cd my-project".  
6. I executed "stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc".  
7. I executed "stack build".  
  
Then, I got the same error. Did I miss any steps?

Comment: The error said 
`ghc.exe: could not execute: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.2\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe`.

Comment: There's no guarantee that this will solve the problem. _However_: are you certain that the STACK_ROOT environment variable change actually affected the command window you were using?

Comment: Yes. I did `echo %STACK_ROOT%` and got 'C:\stack_root' before I executed `stack build`. Also, I added 'C:\stack_root' to PATH environment variable. I did `echo %PATH%` and the result contained ''C:\stack_root'.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the `STACK_ROOT` thing, but it is not changing where the compiler is looking for `gcc.exe`. There was stuff created in the new stack root folder, but the main installation is still in the same place.